# SignedExtension and nested calls

Tags: runtime, signed-extensions

Does the `SignedExtension` (`validate`) get executed on a nested call (e.g. sudo.call, scheduler.schedule)? In other words, the call within the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `SignedExtension::validate` will not be called for nested calls. If you want to filter certain calls, you can use `BaseCallFilter` in your runtime. This filter is checked before each dispatch of a call. However, there are also exceptions to this as pallets like `sudo` dispatch without checking any filters.